10 identical socks, 7 drawers: What is the probability that at least one drawer contains 3 or more socks?
My nephew asked me the question thinking I would answer him very quickly, but I got stuck until today.....
There are 7 drawers and 10 socks, all the same. The socks are randomly distributed in the drawers - which can contain from 0 to 10 socks each, i.e. a drawer can be empty.
What is the probability that at least one drawer contains 3 or more socks? 4?

This is an occupancy problem with a very straightforward solution because the small numbers allow a direct computation. What is the underlying point of this exercise?

My nephew asked me the question thinking I would answer him very quickly, but I got stuck until today... I put this comment into the post.

Ah, that is fun. I said that it is straightforward to compute, but when little nephews ask these type of questions then different approaches of answering are necessary. (In the same way that my physics questions from my son where not very well received). Rain drop trails on a car window prefer certain paths. Why? and Why does something round roll down faster than something square?

Exactly, difficult to make simple...

You do need further conditions on the problem description to make it answerable.

@Adam The socks are distributed uniformly among the drawers, I guess.

@SextusEmpiricus Thank you for the links, awesome!

Stating in the comments that this question is simple, I feel obliged to at least provide the simple answer.
There are $7^{10} = 282475249$ different distributions of the socks. We can have one two or three drawers with more than three socks.
Let's consider just the event that the first drawer contains 3 socks. That is equal to ${10 \choose 3} 6^7$ cases (≈ 11.89% probability). Then we have to deal with the drawer containing more than 3 socks and the other drawers containing 3 or more socks and the cases of double counting when two or more drawers contain 3 or more socks.
At this point I just want to compute it directly like below:
count = 0
for (a in 1:7) {
for (b in 1:7) {
for (c in 1:7) {
for (d in 1:7) {
for (e in 1:7) {
for (f in 1:7) {
for (g in 1:7) {
for (h in 1:7) {
for (i in 1:7) {
for (j in 1:7) {
   add = 0
   for (k in 1:7) {
     if (sum(c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) == k) >= 3) 
     {
        add = 1
     }
   }
   count = count + add
}}}}}}}}}}

count

But the silly online compilers don't allow me to make such computations, and I don't have my computer nearby.
An approximation by simulation is 85%
set.seed(1)

k = replicate(10^4, { 
    x = sample(1:7, 10, replace = 1)
    max(table(x))
})
mean(k>=3)


Thank you for your answer ! I understand now the comment of @AdamO : a drawer can be empty…
